# WebView error in android

Tags: android, webview

Resouce id is showing error and i dont know what wrong i have done

this is main java file 
the line `myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);` is showing error and if i changed the id to something else app is crashing in emulator and also in physical device

and its not about null pointer the user marked it as a duplicate i would request u to please improve your knowledge(no offence)

```
package com.piyush.gangatechnicalcampus;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private WebView myWebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.easyonlineconverter.com");
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (myWebView.canGoBack()) {
            myWebView.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

here is the activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.piyush.gangatechnicalcampus.MainActivity">

    <WebView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" >

        <WebView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            tools:ignore="ObsoleteLayoutParam" />
    </WebView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

and this is AndroidMainfest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.piyush.gangatechnicalcampus">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" ></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:context=".MainActivity">
        <item android:id="@+id/action_settings" android:title="@string/action_settings"
            android:orderInCategory="100" app:showAsAction="never" />
    </menu>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Add you xml file too..

Comment: upload your complete error log as well

Comment: added xml files and which error log as i am new to android please guide me. should i give u event log?

Comment: Go this link. you will be getting webview project example. https://github.com/pacificregmi/SimpleAndroidWebViewExample

Comment: you have not created id for your webview in xml file, try my post, its working

Comment: i want to add go back function in app @ShabbirDhangot how can add


    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(WebView.canGoBack()) {
            WebView.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    } 
this is giving me error (cannot be referenced form static context )

Comment: Instead of `WebView.canGoBack()` use `myWebView.canGoBack()`. same for the goBack() function() . `myWebView` is object of your Webview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try out this:
in xml file:

```
    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/web_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

in java file:

```
private WebView webView;
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_view);`
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.loadUrl("http://google.com");
```

Comment: you have not created id for your webview in your xml file

Comment: You should add your comment as explanation to the question itself.